# Coding Mahalanobis and Manhattan distance with R

Tags: r, distance

I want to code by hand in R, for a data analysis project Manhattan distance and Mahalanobis. I already coded Euclidean distance as the following :

```
euclideanDist <- function(a, b){
  d = 0
  for(i in c(1:(length(a)-1) ))
  {
    d = d + (a[[i]]-b[[i]])^2
  }
  d = sqrt(d)
  return(d)
}
```

I want to do the same with the Manhattan distance, I thought to elevate to the square and then to take the square root but I dont know if it is the best thing to do :

```
manhattan <- function(a, b){
  d = 0
  for(i in c(1:(length(a)-1) ))
  {
    d = d + sqrt((a[[i]]-b[[i]])^2)
  }
  d = sqrt(d)
  return(d)
}
```

Finally I want to try the Mahalanobis distance but I don't knwo how to compute it, I know it is

$$D_{M}(x)={\sqrt  {(x-\mu )^{T}\Sigma ^{{-1}}(x-\mu )}}$$

Where $\Sigma$ is the covariance Matrix and $\mu$ the mean.

Can you tell me if my Manhattan distance is well programmed and help me knowing hot to program the Mahalanobis distance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what `a` and `b` are in your code. But I am assuming that either are ordered pairs, and you need a distance between these two points.

Euclidean:

```
euclideanDist <- function(a, b){
  d<-(a-b)^2
  d<-sum(d)
  d<-sqrt(d)
  return(d)
}
```

[Manhattan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry):

```
manhattanDist<-function(a,b){
  d<-abs(a-b)
  d<-sum(d)
  return(d)
}
```

I am not sure what do you mean by calculating the mahalanobis for similar a and b. As far as I know, for Mahalanobis, you need a collection of random variables.